# Generate predicates from Json

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a WEB API done in Asp.Net that returns some points of interest in JSON. In prolog I obtain it by doing this:

```
poi(X):- http_client:http_get('http://localhost:XXXXX/api/PontosInteresse',X,[]).
```

This returns something of the sort:

```
X = '[{"ID":1,"nome":"teste","descricao":"gfds","tempoEstimado":21,"acessibilidade":1,"localID":1,"local":{"ID":1,"nome":"porto","latitude":"21","longitude":"-21","ApplicationUserID":null},"categoriaID":1,"categoria":{"ID":1,"nome":"cultura","ApplicationUserID":null},"hashtags":null,"ApplicationUserID":null},{"ID":2,"nome":"teste2","descricao":"qweqwe","tempoEstimado":13,"acessibilidade":1,"localID":1,"local":{"ID":1,"nome":"porto","latitude":"21","longitude":"-21","ApplicationUserID":null},"categoriaID":1,"categoria":{"ID":1,"nome":"cultura","ApplicationUserID":null},"hashtags":null,"ApplicationUserID":null},{"ID":3,"nome":"teste3","descricao":"fgdfg","tempoEstimado":0,"acessibilidade":0,"localID":1,"local":{"ID":1,"nome":"porto","latitude":"21","longitude":"-21","ApplicationUserID":null},"categoriaID":1,"categoria":{"ID":1,"nome":"cultura","ApplicationUserID":null},"hashtags":null,"ApplicationUserID":null}]'.
```

How can I transform this to a bunch of predicates, in the form of:

```
poi(ID, Nome, Descricao, TempoEstimado, Acessibilidade, LocalId).
local(ID, Nome, Latitude, Longitude).
```

Comment: There's a json package for SWI-Prolog, if you're using that implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an example of how to access **untyped** content:

```
:- use_module(library(http/json)).

tj :-   X = '[{"ID":1,"nome":"teste","descricao":"gfds","tempoEstimado":21,"acessibilidade":1,"localID":1,"local":{"ID":1,"nome":"porto","latitude":"21","longitude":"-21","ApplicationUserID":null},"categoriaID":1,"categoria":{"ID":1,"nome":"cultura","ApplicationUserID":null},"hashtags":null,"ApplicationUserID":null},{"ID":2,"nome":"teste2","descricao":"qweqwe","tempoEstimado":13,"acessibilidade":1,"localID":1,"local":{"ID":1,"nome":"porto","latitude":"21","longitude":"-21","ApplicationUserID":null},"categoriaID":1,"categoria":{"ID":1,"nome":"cultura","ApplicationUserID":null},"hashtags":null,"ApplicationUserID":null},{"ID":3,"nome":"teste3","descricao":"fgdfg","tempoEstimado":0,"acessibilidade":0,"localID":1,"local":{"ID":1,"nome":"porto","latitude":"21","longitude":"-21","ApplicationUserID":null},"categoriaID":1,"categoria":{"ID":1,"nome":"cultura","ApplicationUserID":null},"hashtags":null,"ApplicationUserID":null}]',
    open_any(string(X), read, S, Close, []),
    json_read(S, T),
    Close,
    maplist(convert, T, C),
    maplist(writeln, C).

convert(json(L),
    poi(ID, Nome, Descricao, TempoEstimado, Acessibilidade, LocalId)
    / local(IDLoc, NomeLoc, Latitude, Longitude)
) :-
    maplist({L}/[F,V]>>memberchk(F=V, L),
        ['ID', nome, descricao, tempoEstimado, acessibilidade, localID],
        [ID, Nome, Descricao, TempoEstimado, Acessibilidade, LocalId]),
    memberchk(local=json(LL), L),
    maplist({LL}/[F,V]>>memberchk(F=V, LL),
        ['ID', nome, latitude, longitude],
        [IDLoc, NomeLoc, Latitude, Longitude]).
```

that yields

```
poi(1,teste,gfds,21,1,1)/local(1,porto,21,-21)
poi(2,teste2,qweqwe,13,1,1)/local(1,porto,21,-21)
poi(3,teste3,fgdfg,0,0,1)/local(1,porto,21,-21)
```

*edit*

here is the equivalent code that avoids the powerful [library(yall)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)

```
convert(json(L),
    poi(ID, Nome, Descricao, TempoEstimado, Acessibilidade, LocalId)
    / local(IDLoc, NomeLoc, Latitude, Longitude)
) :-
    maplist(field_value(L),
        ['ID', nome, descricao, tempoEstimado, acessibilidade, localID],
        [ID, Nome, Descricao, TempoEstimado, Acessibilidade, LocalId]),
    memberchk(local=json(LL), L),
    maplist(field_value(LL),
        ['ID', nome, latitude, longitude],
        [IDLoc, NomeLoc, Latitude, Longitude]).

field_value(Fields, Field, Value) :-
    memberchk(Field=Value, Fields).
```

Comment: CapelliC thanks for the answer. When I try your code I get this error: ERROR: apply:maplist_/3: Undefined procedure: (>>)/4
   Exception: (13) >>({['ID'=1, nome=teste, descricao=gfds, tempoEstimado=21, acessibilidade=1, ... = ...|...]}/[_G2636, _G2639], memberchk(_G2636=_G2639, ['ID'=1, nome=teste, descricao=gfds, tempoEstimado=21, acessibilidade=1, localID=1, ... = ...|...]), 'ID', _G2616) ? break Do you think you can help me understand it?

Comment: the error is caused by library(yall), a lambda utility, that's been implemented in relatively new versions. I'll show the equivalent plain code...